# How to increment and decrement machine code in radare2?

Tags: radare2, machine-code

I watched a video (I believe it was a talk by the author of radare2) of how to increment machine code in radare2 very easily, simply by hitting 'c' and then using + and - to respectively increment and decrement machine code.

However, now, when I hit v and then p to get to the visual mode where I can see disassembled code, I hit c, I can move the cursor around, but I can't increment and decrement machine code any longer.

Am I remembering this incorrectly? Clearly I need to take better notes, because I find it hard to find this information in the myriad of online "cheat sheets" and tutorials that always seem to talk about something else than what I'm really after.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: Remember to execute with -w. (sigh)

Comment: or just use `oo+`